# Get all rows who are connected via foreign-key within the same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a table called tbl_report. Within this table there are monthly based reports which can be connected each other via their reportID.

table structure

```
reportID
year
month
topic
fk_reportID
```

content

```
1  2021  01  Topic10  NULL
2  2021  01  Topic11  NULL
3  2021  02  Topic20  1
4  2021  03  Topic30  3
```

I would have all reports which are connected directly via fk_reportID but also reports which are connected indirectly.

For the given example:

I select reportID 4 and the result should be:

```
1  2021  01  Topic10
3  2021  02  Topic20
4  2021  03  Topic30
```

But it should be the same result aswell when reportID 1 is selected.

Thanks!

Comment: What database system are you using ? please update the tag accordingly. Please also include the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that there is a more eloquent way to do this, but what you are trying to do is basically search this table in two directions:

reportID-> fk_reportID and then fk_reportID -> reportID.

Using a recursive CTE you can do both searches, but I believe you have to do them separately.  So the following will get you what you requested, but again this may be a little clunky. Just change the value of @ID to get your results:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (reportID int, [year] varchar(5),[month] varchar(3), topic varchar(20), fk_reportID int)

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
(1,'2021','01','Topic10',  NULL),
(2,'2021','01','Topic11',  NULL),
(3,'2021','02','Topic20',  1),
(4,'2021','03','Topic30',  3)



DECLARE @nID int = 1
CREATE TABLE #FirstRun (reportID int, [year] varchar(5),[month] varchar(3), topic varchar(20), fk_reportID int)

;WITH CTE as
(
    SELECT * FROM #tmp
    WHERE reportID = @nID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.* FROM #tmp t1 
        INNER JOIN CTE on t1.reportID = cte.fk_reportID

)
INSERT INTO #FirstRun(reportID,[year],[month],topic,fk_reportID)
SELECT reportID,[year],[month],topic,fk_reportID from CTE

;WITH SecondRun as
(
    SELECT * from #tmp
    WHERE reportID = @nID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.* from #tmp t1 INNER JOIN SecondRun SR on t1.fk_reportID = SR.reportID

)
SELECT reportID,[year],[month],topic 
    FROM SecondRun
UNION
select reportID,[year],[month],topic from #FirstRun
```